# git SSH : Could not resolve hostname github: Name or service not known fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, github, ssh

git SSH: $ git push -u  origin master ssh: Could not resolve hostname GitHub: Name or service not known fatal: Could not read from remote repository.  Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the reposit

Any Solution, please

Comment: You'll need to show your `.git/config` file, for starters.

Comment: The host is not `GitHub` but `github.com`

Comment: [core]
 repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = false
 bare = false
 logallrefupdates = true
 symlinks = false
 ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
 url = git@github:Alhiane/alhiane-blog
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:Alhiane/alhiane-blog
```

Answer (score -1):

Just for the sake of completeness, I encountered a similar issue today: Running `git pull` ending with the error message `ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com`.

Ping also reported 100% packet loss. However, after a few minutes the issue went away. So, sometimes this issue is indeed temporary as the first error message suggested. Especially in cases, when nothing on the user's side changed.

---

Added to add, that I again encountered this behaviour. I called `git push` from within the repo after making a commit and got an error. A little while later, I repeated the command and it worked.

Here's a copy from my Terminal with all personal data removed.

```
user@host:~/myGitHubRepo/somePath$ git push
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Name or service not known
fatal: Konnte nicht vom Remote-Repository lesen.

Bitte stellen Sie sicher, dass die korrekten Zugriffsberechtigungen bestehen
und das Repository existiert.
user@host:~/myGitHubRepo/somePath$ git push
Zähle Objekte: 7, Fertig.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Komprimiere Objekte: 100% (6/6), Fertig.
Schreibe Objekte: 100% (7/7), 677 bytes | 677.00 KiB/s, Fertig.
Total 7 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (4/4), completed with 4 local objects.
To github.com:myGitHubRepo.git
   04c0b15..817145d  master -> master
```

Sorry for the partly German error messages.

My computer is a PC which is connected by cable to our LAN. I expect a cabled network to be less brittle than a wireless one, but maybe the network was somewhat(?) down when I first called `git push`, I don't know.

While the error message from ssh might hint to a network problem, git was a bit more enigmatic. Git's message roughly translates to: *make sure you have got the proper permissions and that the repository exists*.