# ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Temporary failure in name resolution fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, github, pull

Not able to `PULL` the Github repository, getting the following error

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.


Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Comment: It looks like a network issue.

Comment: Check first if https://stackoverflow.com/q/9393409/6309 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/61208497/6309 can help

Answer (score -1):

i've checked my ssh and `git remote -v` or `ssh -T git@github.com` and all worked fine, and i was still getting the error. the reason was because i initialized on the wrong working folder. meaning, after you mkdir for your working area, you then supposed to init in the current folder you are. and i made the mistake of going into the folder of the working area, and then git init it, and thus git didn't know where is my working area.

example:

this is the mistake:

```
current-dir$> mkdir new-git
current-dir$> cd new-git
current-dir/new-git$> git init new-git
```

correct procedure is:

```
current-dir$> mkdir new-git
current-dir$> git init new-git
```

it might help to check.